# Exclude Spring Controller method from model binding through annotated @ModelAttribute method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting an invalid request for method getIndex because request parameter id is missing.  Can I specify that I don't want model binding for that requestmapping method?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping ("/admin/admins")
public class AdminUserController {
@RequestMapping (method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getIndex(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("admins",userService.findAllAdmins());
        return "admin/admins/list";
    }

@ModelAttribute("user")
    public AdminUser getAdminUser(@RequestParam("id") Integer id) {
        return userService.findAdminById(id);
    }




    @RequestMapping (method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String registerAdmin(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") AdminUser user, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap model)  {

        model.addAttribute("roles", userRoleService.findAll());
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "admin/admins/form";
        } 
        else if (!user.getPassword().equals(user.getConfirmPassword())) {
            bindingResult.addError(new FieldError("user","confirmPassword", "Passwords don't match"));
            return "admin/admins/form";
        }
        else {
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encodePassword(user.getPassword(), null));
            try {
                userService.save(user);
                return "redirect:/admin/admins";
            } catch(ApplicationException ce) {
                bindingResult.addError(new FieldError("user", "email", "Email already registered"));
                return "admin/admins/form";
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean you are getting invalid request for `getAdminUser()` method? It doesn't make sense that you would get that for `getIndex`.

Comment: HTTP Status 400 - Required Integer parameter 'id' is not present when I try to get a list of users getIndex()

Comment: Exactly, that is in the method `getAdminUser()` not `getIndex()`.

Comment: yes..but the binding is executed before every requestmapping methods, can I exclude getIndex?

Comment: just to clear it up sorry..using spring 3.2, the new method annotation @ModelAttribute..http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: I'm not sure how Spring is supposed to know to pass your request id parameter to the `@ModelAttribute` method.

Comment: Put your `@RequestMappings` at the method level instead of the controller (class) level. It's getting confused and trying to execute `getAdminUser()` when you're trying to execute `getIndex()`.

Comment: As an aside, dunno if that is intended for exposure to the public internet or whatever, but that controller is highly vulnerable to query-string injection attacks.  If it is public, you should restrict the databinder to only apply to fields you intend to be edited (password and confirmPassword it would appear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your id parameter optional

```
@ModelAttribute("user")
public AdminUser getAdminUser(@RequestParam(value="id", required=false) Integer id) {
    if(id==null){
        return new AdminUser();
    }
    return userService.findAdminById(id);
}
```

Edit: Or loose the ModelMap paramter:

```
@RequestMapping (method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getIndex() {
    return new ModelAndView("admin/admins/list", "admins",userService.findAllAdmins());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Would that be a good practice? It would create a new AdminUser object on every request regardless if I need it in the model or not for that particular request right?  I'm new to Spring, should I move the getIndex method to another controller?